# How can I request a new access token automatically to get feed of an open Group?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

I have an open group on Facebook and I would like to display the feed from that group on my web site.  I can do it just fine, the PHP code I created gets the feed and it is formatted just like I want to send the user back to the facebook group.  It's great until the access token apparently expires after a couple hours.  The only way I can figure out to get a new valid access token is to manually go back to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path={GROUP ID} every couple of hours to get a new access token and then copy and paste it into my php code.  I can't do that for obvious reasons.  Is there a way to request a new valid access token through a cron or someother means, that I can then store in my database and use until it expires and my site grabs a new access token?  I have read all day long on this and can't find an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the 60 day token, call the `fb_exchange_token` URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[ID]&client_secret=[SECRET]&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[PreviousToken]
```

The docs say that you can't do this through a cron; not sure how that's gated, and I've not (yet) tried it, but the best would be to do this as soon as you get the initial token. You can extend the token once per day. It lasts 60 days, so hope that the user returns within 60 days.

Comment: But I don't have an app.  I just want the feed from the group.  I can get it no problem, but I have to go back every 2 hours to get a new access token.  If I were to create a pointless app could I use that just to get a token?

Comment: For a long token, yes, you'd need an app. When you visit the API explorer you're actually getting a token given by Facebook's app; if you knew the secret for that app you could extend the token - but you won't know the secret as it's, well, secret. So yes, create yourself an app, just for this if needed.